# com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer как устранить ошибку SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL?

Tags: java, ssl, https, http-server

Создал https сервер:

```
    public void startHttpsServer() {
    try {
        httpsServer = com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer.create();
        httpsServer.bind(new InetSocketAddress(httpsPort), 5);
        httpsServer.createContext("/getVersion", new VersionHandler());
        httpsServer.createContext("/sysInfo", new SysInfoHandler());
        httpsServer.createContext("/cashRegisterService", new CashRegisterHandler());
        httpsServer.createContext("/printService", new PrintServiceHandler());

        char[] storepass = "testtest".toCharArray();
        char[] keypass = "testtest".toCharArray();

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(HttpServer.class.getResourceAsStream("test.jks"), storepass);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, keypass);

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(ks);
        SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ssl.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        httpsServer.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(ssl) {
            public void configure (HttpsParameters params) {

                // get the remote address if needed
                InetSocketAddress remote = params.getClientAddress();

                SSLContext c = getSSLContext();
                SSLParameters sslparams = c.getDefaultSSLParameters();
                // get the default parameters

                params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
                // statement above could throw IAE if any params invalid.
                // eg. if app has a UI and parameters supplied by a user.
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.addLogLine("HttpServerError",e.toString(), e);
    } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    httpsServer.setExecutor(executor);
    httpsServer.start();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Еще вроди-как нужно создать хранилище с сертификатом. Выполнил:

```
keytool -v -genkey -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Developers, O=NA, L=Kiev, C=UA" -alias parent -storetype jks -keystore test.jks -validity 365 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storepass testtest -keypass testtest
```

Запускаю свой сервис и выполняю curl:

```
curl -v -H -GET  https://localhost:32910/sysInfo
```

результат:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 32910 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:32910 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:32910
```

Что я упускаю или делаю неправильно? что не так с SSL?

Comment: А просто браузер тоже не коннектится?

Comment: неа :( ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: а почему у Вас два раза `httpsServer.start()`?

Comment: поправил, но не повлияло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в строке:

```
ks.load(HttpServer.class.getResourceAsStream("test.jks"), storepass);
```

правильно указывать с /test.jks
пример:

```
ks.load(HttpServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.jks"), storepass);
```

также test.jks должен быть в /main/resources